# How to select from one database and insert it into another?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 MySQL databases with 1 table in each one.

> Table1 (name,steamid,time)
>   Table2 (name,steamid)

Now I want to select all data from Table1, where the Time (in sec.) is for example more than 500. And then I want to insert the name and the steamid into the Table 2, if the steamid does not exist in Table2.

How is this possible? The tables are in 2 databases and not in the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  like this

```
insert into db1.Tbl1(name,steamid) values (select name, steamid from db2.Tbl2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Mysql 5.7 syntax slightly changed

```
INSERT INTO db1.Tbl1(field1,field2) SELECT field1, field2 FROM db2.Tbl2
```

Source: [Mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)